# How to preprocess a document before indexation?

Tags: elasticsearch, twitter, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using logstash and elasticsearch to collect tweet using the Twitter plug in. My problem is that I receive a document from twitter and I would like to make some preprocessing before indexing my document. Let's say that I have this as a document result from twitter:

```
{
    "tweet": {
       "tweetId": 1025,
       "tweetContent": "Hey this is a fake document for stackoverflow #stackOverflow #elasticsearch",
       "hashtags": ["stackOverflow", "elasticsearch"],
       "publishedAt": "2017 23 August",
       "analytics": {
           "likeNumber": 400,
           "shareNumber": 100,
       }
    },
    "author":{
       "authorId": 819744,
       "authorAt": "the_expert",
       "authorName": "John Smith",
       "description": "Haha it's a fake description"
    }
}
```

Now out of this document that twitter is sending me I would like to generate two documents:
the first one will be indexed in twitter/tweet/1025 :

```
# The id for this document should be the one from tweetId `"tweetId": 1025`
{
    "content": "Hey this is a fake document for stackoverflow #stackOverflow #elasticsearch", # this field has been renamed
    "hashtags": ["stackOverflow", "elasticsearch"],
    "date": "2017/08/23", # the date has been formated
    "shareNumber": 100 # This field has been flattened
}
```

The second one will be indexed in twitter/author/819744:

```
# The id for this document should be the one from authorId `"authorId": 819744 `
{
   "authorAt": "the_expert",
   "description": "Haha it's a fake description"
}
```

I have defined my output as follow:

```
output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "twitter"
    document_type => "tweet"
  }
}
```

How can I process the information from twitter?

**EDIT:**

So my full config file should look like:

```
input {
  twitter {
      consumer_key => "consumer_key"
      consumer_secret => "consumer_secret"
      oauth_token => "access_token"
      oauth_token_secret => "access_token_secret"
      keywords => [ "random", "word"]
      full_tweet => true
      type => "tweet"
  }
}
filter {
  clone {
    clones => ["author"]
  }
  if([type] == "tweet") {
    mutate {
      remove_field => ["authorId", "authorAt"]
    }
  } else {
     mutate {
      remove_field => ["tweetId", "tweetContent"]
     }
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  if [type] == "tweet" { 
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
      index => "twitter"
      document_type => "tweet"
      document_id => "%{[tweetId]}"
    }
  } else {
     elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
      index => "twitter"
      document_type => "author"
      document_id => "%{[authorId]}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the clone filter plugin on logstash.

With a sample logstash configuration file that takes a JSON input from stdin and simply shows the output on stdout:

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => json
    type => "tweet"
  }
}
filter {
    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "tweetId" => "%{[tweet][tweetId]}"
        "content" => "%{[tweet][tweetContent]}"
        "date" => "%{[tweet][publishedAt]}"
        "shareNumber" => "%{[tweet][analytics][shareNumber]}"
        "authorId" => "%{[author][authorId]}"
        "authorAt" => "%{[author][authorAt]}"
        "description" => "%{[author][description]}"
      }
    }
    date {
        match => ["date", "yyyy dd MMMM"]
        target => "date"
    }
    ruby {
      code => '
        event.set("hashtags", event.get("[tweet][hashtags]"))
    '
    }
    clone {
      clones => ["author"]
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => ["author", "tweet", "message"]
    }
    if([type] == "tweet") {
      mutate {
        remove_field => ["authorId", "authorAt", "description"]
      }
    } else {
      mutate {
        remove_field => ["tweetId", "content", "hashtags", "date", "shareNumber"]
      }
    }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Using as input:

```
{"tweet": { "tweetId": 1025, "tweetContent": "Hey this is a fake document", "hashtags": ["stackOverflow", "elasticsearch"], "publishedAt": "2017 23 August","analytics": { "likeNumber": 400, "shareNumber": 100 } }, "author":{ "authorId": 819744, "authorAt": "the_expert", "authorName": "John Smith", "description": "fake description" } }
```

You would get these two documents:

```
    {
           "date" => 2017-08-23T00:00:00.000Z,
       "hashtags" => [
        [0] "stackOverflow",
        [1] "elasticsearch"
    ],
           "type" => "tweet",
        "tweetId" => "1025",
        "content" => "Hey this is a fake document",
    "shareNumber" => "100",
     "@timestamp" => 2017-08-23T20:36:53.795Z,
       "@version" => "1",
           "host" => "my-host"
}
{
    "description" => "fake description",
           "type" => "author",
       "authorId" => "819744",
     "@timestamp" => 2017-08-23T20:36:53.795Z,
       "authorAt" => "the_expert",
       "@version" => "1",
           "host" => "my-host"
}
```

You could alternatively use a ruby script to flatten the fields, and then use rename on mutate, when necessary.

If you want elasticsearch to use authorId and tweetId, instead of default ID, you could probably configure elasticsearch output with document_id.

```
output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  if [type] == "tweet" { 
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
      index => "twitter"
      document_type => "tweet"
      document_id => "%{[tweetId]}"
    }
  } else {
     elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
      index => "twitter"
      document_type => "tweet"
      document_id => "%{[authorId]}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I edit my question to show you the overall config file. How can I manage the renaming of a field or the flattening of a field?

Comment: Yeah it works just one question before validating the answer:
add_field seem to stringify my hashtags array. Is there a way to solve this issue and to have `["stackOverflow", "elasticsearch"]` instead of `"stackOverflow,elasticsearch"` I  tried add_tag but didn't seem to work as add_field

Comment: I posted a slightly different solution, using a ruby script to copy the nested hashtags array into a top level field. Works with logstash 5.x, syntax has changed. In theory a simple mutate / split should do the trick, but somehow it's not working. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

Comment: One last question, is it better to use a ruby script or a mutate one?

Comment: I prefer to avoid ruby scripts, having had performance issues with them in the past. But I'm not sure it's a rule. Anyway, if you can always try both approaches and use logstash API to decide. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-logstash.html#monitoring